# Как сделать так, чтобы два блока при скролле двигались разной скоростью?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Суть в том, что есть два блока, которые будут двигать с разной скоростью при скролле

Answer (score 1):

есть javascript библиотека relaxjs, позволяющая легко добиться такого эффекта.
вот отличный тюториал:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAxt0Z7IXIo